# Internet Explorer fixed position is not working properly

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, validation, css-position

my navigation bar and twitter box are not displaying properly.  These are fixed in position. If you see they are at the bottom of the page currently.  Where they should not be.

On other pages of my website these two elements work fine even in IE.  My home page has a different header and footer than the rest of my pages so I tried to pinpoint the problem, but even If I got rid of all the code except for the nav bar and twitter box it seems the problem still existed which really confused me.

I am stumped and can not see clearly now. I just want to punch IE in the face, but I know it is probably something I have done or changed recently because this did not use to happen.

Also somehting that seems to have also been affected around the same time, and I am guessing is related is, when you click the log in link there is now a seperation from the top image and the login form part.  Again this happens only on my home page but in this case with the log in form, it also also shows up in Chrome.

Could any one help me determine the issue here so I can move on with my life.  (I am using IE8 for my testing)

Thanks!!!

EDIT----------

I noticed from the answers below that my  was somehow in my body tag. However here is my code, where it obviously is not within my body tag and is the first line in code. Except of course since this page is a custom wordpress template I have the templates name on the top.  The  tag seems to be empty and all my head declarations are also within the body.  Very odd.... Does any one got any ideas to why this may happening. it appears it is on all browsers.  My entire  page code below.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home Page
*/
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">     
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">     <title><?php bp_page_title(); ?></title>  <?php do_action( 'bp_head' ); ?>
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress <?php bloginfo('version'); ?>" /> <!-- leave this for stats -->       <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />        <?php if ( function_exists( 'bp_sitewide_activity_feed_link' ) ) : ?>           <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php _e('Site Wide Activity RSS Feed', 'buddypress' ) ?>" href="<?php bp_sitewide_activity_feed_link() ?>" />     <?php endif; ?>     <?php if ( function_exists( 'bp_member_activity_feed_link' ) && bp_is_member() ) : ?>           <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php bp_displayed_user_fullname() ?> | <?php _e( 'Activity RSS Feed', 'buddypress' ) ?>" href="<?php bp_member_activity_feed_link() ?>" />        <?php endif; ?>     <?php if ( function_exists( 'bp_group_activity_feed_link' ) && bp_is_group() ) : ?>         <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php bp_current_group_name() ?> | <?php _e( 'Group Activity RSS Feed', 'buddypress' ) ?>" href="<?php bp_group_activity_feed_link() ?>" />        <?php endif; ?>     <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php _e( 'Blog Posts RSS Feed', 'buddypress' ) ?>" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />     <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php _e( 'Blog Posts Atom Feed', 'buddypress' ) ?>" href="<?php bloginfo('atom_url'); ?>" />       <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />       

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-21029219-7']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

<!-- script for glossary highlight -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.aapltrader.com/wp-content/themes/Equilibrium/js/highlight.js"> </script>


<script type='text/javascript'>

// Browser safe opacity handling function

function setOpacity( value ) {
 document.getElementById("styled_popup").style.opacity = value / 10;
 document.getElementById("styled_popup").style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value * 10 + ')';
}

function fadeInMyPopup() {
 for( var i = 0 ; i <= 100 ; i++ )
   setTimeout( 'setOpacity(' + (i / 10) + ')' , 8 * i );
}

function fadeOutMyPopup() {
 for( var i = 0 ; i <= 100 ; i++ ) {
   setTimeout( 'setOpacity(' + (10 - i / 10) + ')' , 8 * i );
 }

 setTimeout('closeMyPopup()', 800 );
}

function closeMyPopup() {
 document.getElementById("styled_popup").style.display = "none"
}

function fireMyLoginPopup() {
 setOpacity( 0 );
 document.getElementById("styled_popup").style.display = "block";
 fadeInMyPopup();
}
function fireMyStockChartPopup() {
 setOpacity( 0 );
 document.getElementById("stockChart").style.display = "block";
 fadeInMyPopup();
}
</script>
<?php wp_head(); ?>

    </head>



    <body>

<div id='styled_popup' name='styled_popup' style='width: 380px; height: 300px; display:none; position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; zoom: 1'>
<table width='380' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0'>
<tr>

<td height='38' class='login-top'><a class="login-close" href='javascript:fadeOutMyPopup();'>X</a></td>
</tr>

<tr><td colspan='2' style='background-color: #686868; width: 380px; height: 200px;-moz-border-radius:  15px 0 15px 15px;
border-radius: 15px 0  15px 15px;'>

<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="http://www.aapltrader.com/wp-login.php" method="post">

            <p class="login-username">
                <label for="user_login">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" tabindex="10" />
            </p>
            <p class="login-password">
                <label for="user_pass">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" tabindex="20" />
            </p>
            <a class="login-forgot" href="http://www.aapltrader.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword" title="Password Lost and Found">Lost your password?</a>
            <p class="login-remember"><label><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" tabindex="90" /> Remember Me</label></p>
            <p class="login-submit">
                <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button-primary" value="Log In" tabindex="100" />
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="http://www.aapltrader.com/activity/" />
            </p>

        </form>



</td></tr>
</table>
</div>



<div id="container-sales">
  <div id="top-sales">
        <!-- <h1 class="logo"><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1> -->
        <a style="padding-left:0px;" href="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>"><img src="https://www.aapltrader.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/aapltraderlogo.gif"/></a>    
        </div>
    <div id="sales-background">
    <div id="page-wrap-sales">



<?php //get_header(); ?>

<div id="featured"> 



<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="front-bottom">
<div id="leftCol">

<span class="welcomeH2">Learn</span> <span class="welcomeTip">from Successful Traders </span>
<ul>
<li><span class="welcomeText">Tap a global network of AAPLTraders and expand your own trading style!</span></li>
</ul>

<span class="welcomeH2">Connect</span><span class="welcomeTip"> to a Community</span>
<ul>
<li><span class="welcomeText">Share ideas in the AAPLTrader Community Room. Refine your ideas through active groups.</span></li>
</ul>

<span class="welcomeH2">Grow</span><span class="welcomeTip"> Profits</span>
<ul>
<li><span class="welcomeText">Find out what strategies are currently profiting. Get AAPL Alerts during the week and stay plugged in.</span></li>
</ul>
<a href="https://www.aapltrader.com/checkout-2?subscription=2&claim=49d393ce7e1346fa24cecd5d0eb1533d" class="green-button">Get AAPLTrader</a>
<ul style="margin:0 0 0 0;padding:0 0 0 0;">
<li><span  style="font-size:1.5em;padding:10px 0px 0 88px;"> Premium Access  </span><span style="font-size:1.2em;color:#575958;">   $19.99/month</span></li>
<br /><br />
<li> <span style="font-size: 1.4em;color: white;padding: 0px 0px 0 80px;font-weight: bold;">30 Day Money Back Guarantee </span></li>
</ul>
</div>



<div id="sales-video">




 <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="530" height="400" id="csSWF">
                <param name="movie" value="http://www.howtousethinkorswim.com/media/appletrader/justmetus/media/player.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="best" />
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#1a1a1a" />
                <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
                <param name="flashvars" value="thumb=http://www.howtousethinkorswim.com/media/appletrader/justmetus/media/FirstFrame.png&containerwidth=530&containerheight=400&content=justmetus.mp4&autostart=false&blurover=false&autohide=true&smoothing=true&showbranding=false&showstartscreen=true&color=0x1A1A1A,0x1A1A1A" />
                <!--[if !IE]-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.howtousethinkorswim.com/media/appletrader/justmetus/media/player.swf" width="530" height="400">
                    <param name="quality" value="best" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#1a1a1a" />
                    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
                    <param name="flashvars" value="thumb=http://www.howtousethinkorswim.com/media/appletrader/justmetus/media/FirstFrame.png&containerwidth=530&containerheight=400&content=justmetus.mp4&autostart=false&blurover=false&autohide=true&smoothing=true&showbranding=false&showstartscreen=true&color=0x1A1A1A,0x1A1A1A" />
                <!--![endif]-->

                <!--[if !IE]-->
                </object>
                <!--![endif]-->
            </object>



</div>






 <div class="clear"></div>

 </div>


 </div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="latest-wrap">

<div class="content-sales">

<h2 >How it works?</h2> <br /> 

<span class="content-sales-p"> AAPLTrader is a social networking website similar to facebook. We give people a place where they can connect with other like minded people who trade and invest.</span>  
<br /><br /> <br />
<span class="content-sales-p"> Members get access to:</span>
<ul style="font-size:1.4em;"><li style="list-style:disc outside none"><a href="http//www.aapltrader.com/what-is-aapltrader#alerts">AAPL Alerts</a></li>
<li style="list-style:disc outside none;"><a href="http//www.aapltrader.com/what-is-aapltrader#video-update">Video Updates </a></li>
<li style="list-style:disc outside none;"><a href="http//www.aapltrader.com/what-is-aapltrader#community">Community Room</a></li>
<li style="list-style:disc outside none;"><a href="http//www.aapltrader.com/what-is-aapltrader#groups">Groups</a></li> </ul>
<br /> <br />
<span class="content-sales-p">What makes AAPLTrader different are the AAPL Alerts and the Video Updates posted by the AAPLTrader Team on our exclusive wall. To get access, simply click the Get AAPLTrader Button or <a href="http://www.aapltrader.com/what-is-aapltrader">click here</a> for more info.</span>
</div>



<div id="testimonial">
<h2>Testimonials</h2>
<img style="float:left;margin:0 15px 10px 0;" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/quotes.gif" title=" testimonial quotes" />
<p><strong>"First of all I love your advice and analysis. So happy I found it. Its helping me to another level.
 I have been in the market for 30 plus years. I have been doing phenomenal."</strong><br /> <br /><span style="float:right;"> -Paul F. California </span></p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<span id="motto"> "The Facebook for Stock Traders." </span><br/><p> <span style="float: right;"> -Lisa T. New York</span></p>
 </div> 
 <div class="clear"></div>

<div class="push"></div>




</div> <!--Latest Wrap -->




</div> <!--Page Wrap--> 
</div> <!--Sales Background-->  
</div> <!--Container Sales-->
<div class="clear"></div>



<?php do_action( 'bp_after_container' ) ?>
        <?php do_action( 'bp_before_footer' ) ?>


<div id="footer-home">
  <div align="center">
<div class="footer-posts">
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3 , 'category' => 4 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <div class="footer-post">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div> <!-- /footer-posts -->
<div class="clear"></div>

          AAPLTrader &copy; 2011 All Rights Reserved. AAPLTrader does not have any association with Apple Inc. <br /><a href="http://www.aapltrader.com/privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="http://www.aapltrader.com/house-rules">House Rules</a> | <a href="http://www.aapltrader.com/terms-of-use">Terms Of Use</a> | <a href="http://www.aapltrader.com/cancellation-policy">Cancellation Policy</a> | <a href="http://www.aapltrader.com/disclaimer">Disclaimer</a> | <a href="http://www.aapltrader.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/riskstoc.pdf"> Risk of Stocks, Options, Commodities </a><br />

<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?> <a href="http://www.aapltrader.com/affiliate-member"> Affiliate Information </a>  |<?php } else { ?><a href="http://www.aapltrader.com/affiliates-info"> Affiliate Information </a>  |<?php  } ?> 

 <a href="http://www.aapltrader.com/contact-us"> Contact Us </a></div>
        <p class="floatRight"></p>
        <div class="push"></div>

<?php do_action( 'bp_footer' ) ?>
</div>


<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<?php do_action( 'bp_after_footer' ) ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IE you need add an appropriate doc type for fixed position to work.

**Edit:** For some reason your doctype definition is not in the first line. See snapshot below,

[image: DOCTYPE]

Comment: Wow I can't believe I never saw that before.  I really had my head up my ass on this one.  Thanks so much.  It is weird after looking at my code the doctype is specified before the html and head tag yet they appear in the body tag like you mention above.  I will look more into this.  I aprrecitae your help.

Comment: I posted my code for that particular page. As you can see my Doctype is not within my body.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I ended up fixing it after you gave me this advice.  I was gonna try this as a last resort if I could not pinpoint an exact rpblem with the code I had posted above.  But I had a earlier version of this page and so I copied that earlier version into it and it worked. But a lot of the text had changed so I peiced it back with th newer version and it worked. It is really strange becasue I literally copied back the entire page again and it worked fine.  I could not pinpoint any one thing that was making it not work. Weird...

Answer (score 1):

You are coding in xhtml, xhtml is designed to display correctly in every browser, this is assuming of course that your xhtml code passes validation, which it does not.  Firefox is smart enought to find the problem and fix it for you, IE is not.  Make sure your xhtml passes validation, then try again.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aapltrader.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: On that note, using the HTML5 doctype seemed to return less errors: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aapltrader.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=HTML5&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2 -- if you switched doctypes, you'd have less errors to fix.

Comment: Thanks guys,  I noticed that what SKS mentioned was probably the reason why the fixed position is not showing up properly.  Thanks for your help.